# AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/act-ss/cgi-bin/webactivation.cgi

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7

I am getting this error in my `/home/act-ss/logs/error.log`:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/act-ss/cgi-bin/webactivation.cgi
```

I am using Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7, the directory and files inside `/home/act-ss/` are owned by `apache:apache`, and the SELinux context is `unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0`.

My `sites-enabled` look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/act-ss/www"
ServerName mywebsite.com
CustomLog /home/act-ss/logs/access.log combined
ErrorLog /home/act-ss/logs/error.log
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/act-ss/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/home/act-ss/www">
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
Options -Indexes
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also need:

```
<Directory /home/act-ss/cgi-bin/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```